# Too many " or '

Tags: php

I seriously suck at getting the quotes and quotation marks correctly. is there a rule that would help me easily remember?

```
echo "<option value='".$data['recordc']."' . "selected=selected>"  '". data['recordc'] ."' . "</option>";
```

Comment: how about an editor / ide with decent syntax highlighting?

Comment: Use `"` when you want to use `'` inside them, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could easily fix the quotes problem with a  decent editor that has syntax highlighting (even StackOverflow's basic highlighting quickly shows where you went wrong) but that is still a horrible mess to read.

Most of the time if you find yourself outputting too much HTML in an `echo` you are probably best served to do it in a cleaner way, like breaking out of PHP. I would do at the very least:

```
printf('<option value="%1$s" selected=selected>%1$s</option>', $data['recordc']);
```

Answer (score 3):

In general you can use this instead:

```
echo "<option value=\"$data[recordc]\" selected=selected>$data[recordc]</option>";
```

which is a little easier to read.  Array keys don't need to be quoted when used inside a string.

In this case, paolo's `printf` method is nice since the variable is reused

Comment: I thought single quoted strings are not expanded in PHP as in other scripting languages.

Comment: Correct; variables within single quotes are not expanded. Consider also using `{$data['recordc']}` instead of `$data[recordc]`

Comment: @gertas - yeah I got my languages confused.  Fixed now